# Terminal Command Line to find corrupted files

Tags: terminal, photos, photos.app, command-line

I do have just one corrupted photo into my Photos Library.

Is there is any UNIX command line that I can use in terminal in order to scan my Photos Library Folder and find out which file is corrupted?

Answer (score 5):

My first thought was that ImageMagick is bound to have something for this, and indeed it does. You could run something like this

```
find . -name "*.JPG" -exec identify {} \; | grep Corrupt
```

where you can replace `.` with your directory of choice (it will descend recursively) to check each file or image with ImageMagick's `identify` command. Grepping for 'Corrupt' will print you `identify`s output for those files which are in fact corrupt. You could probably trim the output to make it more readable, which would involve some regexing for `grep`.

Obviously, you need to have ImageMagick installed for this. If you use MacPorts, it's as simple as `sudo port install ImageMagick`.